# c++20 cppcoro equivalent of python's asyncio.create_task

Tags: python, c++, c++20, coroutine

I am trying to rewrite some python code with coroutines to c++20 with cppcoro library. But I cant find a c++ equivalent of asyncio.create_task, this is a function which runs task immediately and concurrently.
Here is python code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio
import time

async def getter():
    for i in range(0,10):
        print("ok")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return 100


async def runner():
    n = asyncio.create_task(getter()) # getter started immediately
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2) # let's do something else while getter is running
    print("running") # print some text while getter is still running

    nn = await n  # wait for getter and get result
    print(nn)


asyncio.run(runner())
```

Is there some function in cppcoro library which does same thing as `asyncio.create_task` in python?
Or can someone recommend me better coroutine library?

PS: Does cppcoro have some sleep function, like python's `await asyncio.sleep`

References:

https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Is "asyncio" actually asynchronous (as in using actual threads) or is it just cooperative multithreading (each "thread" having to specify when to run another specific "thread" or to give time to run other "threads" that have been handed over to some system)? The frequent use of `sleep` calls suggests the latter.

Comment: Yes it look it is asynchronous, I've tried to replace `await asyncio.sleep(0.2)` by `time.sleep(0.2)` inside `runner()` and it behaved differently -> running was printed first

Comment: That would mean it *isn't* asynchronous. `getter` doesn't execute unless `runner` explicitly allows it to run.

Comment: when is used `await asyncio.sleep(0.2)`  then "ok" is printed 2x before "running" so during that time 0.2s `getter` can run . But when is used `time.sleep(0.2)` first is printed "running" so getter cant run because runner was not awaiting on anything.

Comment: ... yes. That's what makes it *synchronous*, at least within the context of actual CPU threads. If it were "asynchronous", then there would be nothing `runner` could do to prevent `getter` from running once it had started it.